# how to correct this query?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I have a query that make a inner join 2 tables with this col : 
    words table : wid, wname, wsyn, wlevel
    wordchoice table :wid, ch1, ch2, ch3
but when I want to use this query in bellow , in log cat i receive error !

```
words table : wid, wname, wsyn, wlevel
wordchoice table :wid, ch1, ch2, ch3

public Cursor getText2() {
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
String mySQL1= "select w.wid,w.wname,w.wsyn,c.ch1,c.ch2,c.ch3"
                + " from words w INNER JOIN wordchoice c"
                +"  ON w.wid=c.wid"
                + " where wid=?"
                + " and  wlevel=?"
                ;

String[] args= {"7", "1"};      
Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery(mySQL1,args);
c2.moveToFirst();
return c2;
}
```

whats the problem ?

logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.project.g5/ir.project.g5.test}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: wid: , while compiling: select w.wid,w.wname,w.wsyn,c.ch1,c.ch2,c.ch3 from words w INNER JOIN wordchoice c  ON w.wid=c.wid where wid=? and  wlevel=?
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: wid: , while compiling: select w.wid,w.wname,w.wsyn,c.ch1,c.ch2,c.ch3 from words w INNER JOIN wordchoice c  ON w.wid=c.wid where wid=? and  wlevel=?
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java)
at ir.project.g5.DBHelper.getText2(DBHelper.java:79)
at ir.project.g5.test.onCreate(test.java:141)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
... 12 more
```

Comment: What's the error that you are receiving?

Comment: "_in logcat i recive error_" and "_whats the problem ?_". To answer your question, we need to actually see the logcat output... Use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16813485/edit) button below the question to add it, and don't forget it in future questions..

Comment: Maybe you need to specify in the WHERE clause w.wid and w.wlevel (add the table alias).

Answer (score 6):

`where wid = ?`: it' s ambiguous as you have the same field in both tables. You should prefix it with c or w: `where c.wid = ?`.

The logs you added to your initial post confirm the ambiguity.

Comment: and i have another question :

Comment: in this query i have many parameter , how i can make a private class that return multi parameter ?

Comment: Ask the question in a new post.

Comment: this question is Continuation of main question !

Comment: String z1 = c2.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ch1"));

Answer (score 5):

it is just a presumption:

```
+ " where w.wid=?"
            + " and  w.wlevel=?"
```

Comment: in this query i have many parameter , how i can make a private class that return multi parameter ?

Comment: @hossein feel free to accept my answer if it was helpful.